# getting errors while doing npm in my project

Tags: node.js

I am doing npm install and getting these errors. Cant figure out what is really going on or what am I really missing here. I tried manually installing node-gyp but when I try to run gulp I get "command not found". Totally frustrating

```
16 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/decoder/init.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/4.1.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/soum/Documents/movado/preprocessed/node_modules/css-sprite/node_modules/lwip
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/4.1.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! lwip@0.0.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the lwip@0.0.6 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the lwip package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls lwip
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/soum/Documents/movado/preprocessed/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Please mark the answer, I need the points boost, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/65) with gyp/node-gyp that affects all platforms.

node-gyp is no longer actively supported, so it does not work with newer versions of Node.js. You need to uninstall 4.1.0, so if you are using Homebrew:

```
sudo brew uninstall node.js
```

Then install version 0.12.7, which worked for me (I'm also on Mac OSX - Darwin 14.5.0). I installed 0.12.7 by downloading the pkg from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/).

Comment: This answer (the right one) was so difficult to find!! Thx :)

Comment: My god, thanks. That took me a couple of hours to figure out. If any who comes across this while trying to use sprity / sprity-sass: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500066/sprity-gulp-spriting-image-scss-generator-various-errors-when-run-task

Answer (score 0):

lwip package need to build on install and it's looks like you dont have one (or more) of this packages (gcc, g++, make), so try to run `sudo apt-get install gcc && sudo apt-get install g++ && sudo apt-get install make` and then try again

Comment: I am getting command not found when I try to run sudo  sudo apt-get install gcc

Comment: sorry, I thought you are on ubuntu.
i don't know how to install packages on OS X but i think you know, so you should install them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the "*node-gyp rebuild*" issue by setting npm to point to the preferred version of python v2.7, following instructions at https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation.  I hit this problem installing *lwip* on Ubuntu 14.0.4 with node v4.2.4 and node-gyp v3.5.0.  Solved it by:

```
$ whereis python
    python: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.4m /usr/bin/python2.7 
$ npm config set python /usr/bin/python2.7 
$ npm install lwip
```